# How to auto include?

Tags: php, oop

I have autoload.php . This is running for auto loading my classes. I want to include autoload.php as auto my all php files in main folder.

Like:

```
include_to("index.php, example.php, ............... , other.php");
```

Meantime I know php's running style.

Comment: `include_to`? Never heard of that function and from the unspecific wording of your question I must admit I have no clue what that function *should* do. Maybe you can improve your question a bit and explain what exactly you want to do and into which concrete problem you run?

Comment: sure but explain what? what should that function do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

Instead you should be using [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to create an autoloader, which load file. if it cannot find the class you use.

```
spl_autoload_register(function( $className ){

    $filepath = '/path/to/files/' . strtolower( $className ) . '.php';

    if ( !file_exists( $filepath ) )
    {
        $message  = "Cannot load class: $className. ";
        $message .= "File '$filepath' not found!";
        throw new Exception( $message ); 
    }

    require $filepath;

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) setting to include the file in all your scripts.